# Build JSON string from String and Map<String, String> fields with GSon?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to write a wrapper around JSON for sending websocket messages. I've created this class which allows you to construct with an event name, and then pass an associative array of event data.

How can I parse JSON in the `getString` method like this, here is an example of the JSON:

```
{
    "event_name": "some event name",
    "event_data": {
        "some data": "some data value",
        "some more dat": "some more data value"
    }
}
```

Class:

```
package com.eu.websockets.events.server;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class ServerWebSocketEvent {
    private String eventName;
    private Map<String, String> eventData;

    public ServerWebSocketEvent(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.eventData = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addEventData(String key, String value) {
        eventData.put(key, value);
    }

    public String getString() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to serialize your `ServerWebSocketEvent` to JSON or trying to deserialize it from JSON? The term "parsing" it usually used when deserializing data, but it sounds like you want to serialize. Could you please also show what you have tried so far (in case you have some non-working code)?

Comment: I want to take a string and map and create a JSON string from it @Marcono1234 to send back over to the client. I've included a template in my question.

Answer (score 1):

To have field names different as in the JSON you present you need either to instruct that with `@SerializedName` or in this case you can also set `FieldNamingPolicy` to your `Gson`.

So with `@SerializedName`:

```
    @SerializedName("event_name")
    private String eventName;
    @SerializedName("event_data")
    private Map<String, String> eventData;
    ...
public String getString() {
    return new Gson().toJson(this)
}
```

or with `FieldNamingPolicy` like:

```
public String getString() 
    return new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .setPrettyPrinting() // This one is not needed use if you want to
        .create().toJson(this);
}
```